# Django - redirect from form's clean method

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have a login form in django, where I need to do some extra checks in my clean method:

```
class LoginForm(BootstrapFormMixin, forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, max_length=30)
    password = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_id = self.__class__.__name__.lower()
        self.helper.form_action = ''

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('email'),
            Field('password'),
            Div(
                Submit('submit', _('Login'),
                       css_class="btn btn-block btn-success"),
                css_class=''
            )
        )

    def clean(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        if user:
            company = user.company
            if not company.is_active:
                # here I want to make a redirect; if is it possible to add a flash message it would be perfect!
                raise forms.ValidationError(_('Account activation is not finished yet'))
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('Invalid credentials'))
        return self.cleaned_data
```

It works properly, but when credentials are correct, but user's related object named company is not active (is_active=False) I want to redirect user to another view and add some flash message (using `django.contrib.messages` maybe).

Is it possible to do such redirection?

Thank you!

Comment: It is the *view* that is responsible for returning an HTTP response (including redirects). Forms are responsible for handling the input data. They do not return responses, so you cannot redirect from inside the form.

Comment: How view may know if there should be redirect or something? What should I return from the form?

Answer (score 2):

You could just add a boolean `redirect` attribute to the form to know when to do the redirect:

```
class LoginForm(BootstrapFormMixin, forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.redirect = false

        . . . 

    def clean(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        if user:
            company = user.company
            if not company.is_active:

                self.redirect = True

                raise forms.ValidationError()
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('Invalid credentials'))
        return self.cleaned_data


from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def your_view(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)

     if request.method == 'POST':
          if form.is_valid():
              # whatever
          else:
              if form.redirect:
                  messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR,
                    _('Account activation is not finished yet'))
                  return redirect('wherever')

    return render(request, 'your-template.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could specify a particular error code when you raise the validation error in your form.

```
def clean(self):
        ...
        if not company.is_active:
            # here I want to make a redirect; if is it possible to add a flash message it would be perfect!
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('Account activation is not finished yet'), code='inactive')
```

Then, in the view, you can check the error codes, and redirect if appropriate. You can check the error codes using [`form.errors.as_data()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors.as_data). Since you raise the `ValidationError` in the `clean` method, the error doesn't belong to a particular field so you can access it using the `__all__` key.

```
if form.is_valid():
    # login user then redirect
else:
    for error in form.errors.as_data()['__all__']:
        if error.code == 'inactive':
            messages.warning(request, 'Account is inactive')
            return redirect('/other-url/')
    # handle other errors as normal
```

Answer (score 0):

So I am going to risk a guess that you still want to log the user in FIRST before redirecting the user.

If the above is true, accomplish the PRIMARY functionality of the form first.

The redirect can run in "views" where the user login function needs to run first BEFORE you can redirect the user. Prior to this point there is no need to run additional verification.

Here is how I would write the snippet for the view - only to show the redirect related steps (not the whole view). Assume 'home:index' routes the user to the normal redirect page after login and 'company:add_company_info' routes the user to the aberrant page with the message.

```
if form.is_valid():
    user = form.login(request) # assume this form function calls django authenticate and will return the user if successful
    if user:
        login(request, user)
        if user.company.is_active: # this is assuming the user.company relationship exists
            return redirect('home:index')
        else:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "Please fill in your company information")
            return redirect('company:add_company_info')
```